# Ajax crossdomain request with jquery and BASIC-authentication?

Tags: javascript, ajax, glassfish, cross-domain, basic-authentication

I really appreciated if somebody could tell me what is wrong in that authentication? I take the authentication off from the server to test without it, but javascript is broken.

```
 $('#btnSignIn').click(function() {
            var username = $("#username").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();

    function make_base_auth(user, password) {
            var tok = user + ':' + password;

            var final = "Basic " + $.base64.encode(tok);
            console.log("FINAL---->" +final);
            alert("FINAL---->" +final);

            return final;
}

            $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        url: "http://localhost:8080/SesameService/webresources/users/secured/login",
                        crossDomain: true,
                        dataType: "text",
                        async: false,
                        data: {},
                        beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
                            xhr.setRequestHeader('authorization', make_base_auth(username, password));
                       },
                        success: function() {
                            alert('Thanks for your signin in! ');

                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
                            alert(' Error in signIn-process!! ' +textStatus);
                        }
                    });
        });
```

ERROR: If I take the

```
beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
    xhr.setRequestHeader('authorization', make_base_auth(username, password));
```

-part off from the function, I can get into REST-service. I haven't got authentication on at the moment. Could this be the reason or shoud I have the authentication on in the server when using that header?

```
contentType: "application/json",

@GET
@Path("/secured/login")
@Produces({"text/plain"})
public String login() {

    return "Is it working or not?";
}
```

---

When using beforeSend-part in JS, I got an error:

```
[Exception... "Failure" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location: "JS frame :: http://localhost:8383/Sesame/assets/js/jquery.min.js :: .send :: line 3" data: no] { message="Failure"
, result=2147500037
, name="NS_ERROR_FAILURE"
,
```

If I have understood correctly, "authorization + Basic " in header tells the Glassfish-server, that basic-authentication will be done. After authentication it goes to REST-service and in my case returns json-object to HTML5-client. HTML5-client is running in localhost:8383 and the rest services are running in localhost:8080.

If I run secured rest-services straight in localhost:8080, it is working, so that is not the problem. The problem is that when I am using or trying to use rest-services from different domain localhost:8383, I get get the JS-error  console.log('----ERROR IN ------Siging IN----------'); I am not 100 % sure, but I think that the problem is 401 unauthorized, so cross domain authentication is not working.

Shoud I insert crossDomain: true? I have seen it somewhere, maybe that can be the case?

In serverside I've got the filter:

```
<init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>util.CrossOriginResourceSharingFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>

public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest request, ContainerResponse response) {
    response.getHttpHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.getHttpHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
    response.getHttpHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-type");
    return response;
}
```

---

**QUESTIONS**

1) is it possbile that if server is not configured for authentication and I still use the authorization-header breaks the app and cause the error?

2) What that JS-error means?

Cheers,
Sami

Comment: Can you tell what is the exact problem. I couldn't make much from your post.

Comment: ok, sorry :) I edited the question.